# Add new field in QGIS using Refactor Fields doesn't work

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I want to add a new field named 'TEST' to an existing attribute table (SHP) using Refactor Fields, but when I want to save as new shape, it says:

Evaluation error in expression ""test"": Column 'test' not found

Of course it's not found, since I want to add it as a new field!

Anyone a clue?

It happens both with versions 2.14 as with 2.18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Refactor Fields** tool is useful for reordering the fields that you have already created.

For solving your issue, I think you should use the **Add field to attributes table** algorithm, available from the Processing Toolbox:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But then the "add field" button in Refactor Fields should be removed I guess to make things clear. Thanks again!

Comment: If I want to add 20 new fields, do you know whether I have to "save as" the attribute table 20 times too?

Comment: @Rob I'm glad it was helpful! If you want to 20 new fields, why don't you do it directly from the Attribute Table? Or are you working with a python code?

Comment: Yes, thanks! That's what I will do; the reloading takes so much each time in between though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could just add new columns by opening the attribute table in edit mode and use the 'Add new field' icon (or just `Ctrl+W`)

[image]

Then use the `Refactor fields` to reorder them as you want.

I have also found the `Refactor fields` not to work for adding a field.